# Network - My sites are unavailable

Tags: multisite

I'm asking you your help because I created a network websites :

- example.com/site1/
- example.com/site2/

The installation was done and the tab "My Sites" is available with both websites.
I applied the same Alpine theme to the websites.

However, I don't know if i must to upload some file in the directories /site1 and /site2 to the FTP server. The directories are empty.

If i open the url http://www.example.com/site1/ I got this :

[image: a busy cat]

On the site1 Dashboard, a page is created and configured to be displayed by default as a static page :

[image: a busy cat]

Thank you very much for your advices (and sorry for my poor english!).

Best regards,
Lionel

Comment: There should not be a site1 and site2 folder on your server. Those sites are served via rewrite rules

Comment: Hello Tom J Nowell and thank you very much for your kind help!

I deleted the directories and it works now!

Thank you very much!

Have a nice day.

Best regards,
Lionel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have site1 and site2 folders on your server, so Apache is serving those hence the file listing.

Multisite however is trying to serve those sites using URL rewriting, so deleting those folders should fix the issue